# Inject instance via Controller Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

I'm studying about Dependency Injection, and I need some help to a better understand about Controller Factory.

[image]

I need inject the `SqlReceitaRepository` via `Constructor Injection` in `HomeController`.

**HomeController Constructor**

```
private readonly IReceitaRepository repositorio;

public HomeController(IReceitaRepository repositorio)
{
    if (repositorio == null)
       throw new ArgumentException("repositorio");

    this.repositorio = repositorio;
}
```

With `SqlReceitaRepository` implemented, I can now set up ASP.NET MVC to inject
an instance of it into instances of HomeController, but how can I do that ?

**Detail**: I'm using NHibernate instead Entity Framework.

If needed, the classes that will be created for accomplish this, will belong which layer ?

I read some articles and I saw that I need put a new line in my `Global.asax`

**Global.asax**

```
var controllerFactory = new ReceitaControllerFactory();
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
```

I'm assuming that `ReceitaControllerFactory` should contain the `IControllerFactory` implementation.

But looking at the `IControllerFactory`

```
public interface IControllerFactory
{
    IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName);
    SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName);
    void ReleaseController(IController controller);
}
```

We can see the method CreateController, but how can I inject a instance of `SqlReceitaRepository` into HomeController's instance?

Comment: I love a good illustration, good job, upvoted :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer:

```
IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
{
    return new HomeController(new SqlReceitaRepository());
}
```

But, as you might have noticed, this will only work for one controller type as it is written. More importantly, it's not very maintainable. So the *right* answer is to get a popular DI framework like Ninject, and get the plugins you need for your frameworks (Ninject MVC, e.g.), and then define your bindings and let the framework take care of figuring out the dependencies:

```
Bind<IReceitaRepository>().To<SqlReceitaRepository>();
```

Comment: This was more simple than I imagine, I'm following the studies with Dependency Injection, and the idea is pass through the "hard work" at the beggining and then use some DI Container, like Ninject as you said, Unity, Castle Windsor, etc... Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Using the first approach without a DI Container, will be necessary that the Presentation Layer relies of Data Access Layer, owing to SqlReceitaRepository class is in that layer ?

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: It depends a little on your architecture, but yeah, those are the kinds of problems that arise when you try to roll your own DI helpers. You need to figure out how to handle the construction of objects from all your layers without tightly coupling your other code in a way that it shouldn't be coupled. DI frameworks have pretty much solved these problems already.